# JButton to print a letter

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

How do you print a letter of the button a user clicked and then disable that button

I use a for loop to generate the buttons of each letter

```
   } for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        btnLetters = new JButton(" " + (char) i);
        letterJPanel.add(btnLetters);
        letterJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btnLetters.addActionListener(this);

    }
```

When the button is clicked it should print the letter and then disable the button

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == btnLetters) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ae.getSource() == btnLetters) { } }
```

this part will work only for the very last button created, so I consider it senseless.

Better do something like that

```
if (ae.getSource() instance of JButton &&
    ((JButton ) ae.getSource()).getText().length()==2) {
    PRINT(((JButton ) ae.getSource()).getText().substring(1));
    ((JButton ) ae.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
}
```

where PRINT is the actual printing (however you do that)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class

```
public class ButtonDisabler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(button.getText() + " pressed");
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Then add it to each button

```
btnLetters.addActionListener(new ButtonDisabler());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i would do it like:
(much better to look at, than casting from integer)

```
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    button.setText(""+c);
    ...
}
```

then

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    //assuming you only set the action for the JButtons with letters
    JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    String letter = button.getText();
    print(letter); //for example System.out.println();
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using an inner class will be easier

When creating the button.

```
JButton button = new JButton("A");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      printMethod(button.getLabel()); //You have to implement this...
      this.disable()
});
```

Comment: mKorbel edited my answer, he removed the "this.disable()" line

Comment: @Juan Antonio Gomez Moriano against down_voting, method `disable` isn't part of `official JButtons API`

Comment: @mKorbel I just cheked, the method is there, athough deprecated (since 1.1). Thanks for the clarification.